# Create test table in one sql command

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

My goal is to determine how many times a character string is repeated in a string. An example is how many times 'ab' is repeated in the string 'abcdabcabcdeab'.

Im using Oracle db and have put together this command:

```
with test as (Select 'abcdabcabcdeab' str, 'ab' ab)
Select str, ab, (length(str) - length(replace (str, ab))) / length(ab);
from test;
```

Don't worry about the whole statement, my question is what does 'with test as (Select...)' do?

My guess is it creates a table called test, that would display with a name of `Select 'abcdabcabcdeab' str, 'ab' ab` -I don't understand how `with` creates the table?

Comment: It's a common table expression (also known as a CTE).  It's no different functionally than a derived table in your from clause, just a little easier to read.

Comment: Also called [subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm#i2077142).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general terms, if you have a scenario, where we need to redefine the same `subquery` multiple times, instead we just use the query name defined in the WITH clause, making the query much easier to read. Perhaps, that's why it is called **`subquery factoring`**

For example,

Using the SCOTT schema, for each employee we want to know how many other people are in their department. Using an inline view we might do the following.

```
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
       (SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
        FROM   emp
        GROUP BY deptno) dc
WHERE  e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```

Using a WITH clause this would look like the following.

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
       dept_count dc
WHERE  e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```

The difference seems rather insignificant here.
What if we also want to pull back each employees manager name and the number of people in the managers department? Using the inline view it now looks like this.

```
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc1.dept_count AS emp_dept_count,
       m.ename AS manager_name,
       dc2.dept_count AS mgr_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
       (SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
        FROM   emp
        GROUP BY deptno) dc1,
       emp m,
       (SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
        FROM   emp
        GROUP BY deptno) dc2
WHERE  e.deptno = dc1.deptno
AND    e.mgr = m.empno
AND    m.deptno = dc2.deptno;
```

Using the WITH clause this would look like the following.

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc1.dept_count AS emp_dept_count,
       m.ename AS manager_name,
       dc2.dept_count AS mgr_dept_count
FROM   emp e,
       dept_count dc1,
       emp m,
       dept_count dc2
WHERE  e.deptno = dc1.deptno
AND    e.mgr = m.empno
AND    m.deptno = dc2.deptno;
```

So, bottomline is, we don't need to redefine the same subquery multiple times. Instead we just use the query name defined in the WITH clause, making the query much easier to read.

More detailed info [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is a CTE and also called subquery factoring.

- The SQL WITH clause only works on Oracle 9i release 2 and beyond.
- Formally, the WITH clause is called subquery factoring
- The SQL WITH clause is used when a subquery is executed multiple times
- Also useful for recursive queries (SQL-99, but not Oracle SQL)

We can also use the SQL-99 WITH clause instead of temporary tables. The Oracle SQL WITH clause will compute the aggregation once, give it a name, and allow us to reference it (maybe multiple times), later in the query.

references [About Oracle WITH clause](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm), [Oracle Subquery Factoring](http://dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_subquery_factoring.htm), [Using the WITH clause to simplify complex SQL](http://www.remote-dba.net/oracle_10g_tuning/t_oracle_with_sql_clause.htm), **Thanks [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751573/andrew)**

Comment: Oracle supports [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG) from 11gR2.